# Visual Studio 2010 freezes when using custom Toolbox tools

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I had a set of custom tools in the Toolbox for Visual Studio 2008 that worked fine. These tools come from projects in my solution, that auto-populate my Toolbox.

Now, I've migrated to Visual Studio 2010. After that, when I try to add on a Control the same tools that worked before, my Visual Studio freezes.

Any ideas why?

PS: I already tried 'Reset'ing my Toolbox some times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get it working again by trying a different order of the same steps tried many times before.

The steps where:

1. closed all the opened files inside Visual Studio;
2. Reset my Toolbox;
3. Rebuild my solution and
4. open again the `Design` file where I was trying to add the custom tool.

Not a clue why, but now it's working perfectly.